# Rails generators not working, is spring at fault?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring

When I try to generate anything (model/migration or whatever) I get absolutely nothing. "spring status" tells me that spring is not running, but "spring start" does absolutely nothing also.

**Edit:** I am using rails 4.2.6 and the commands are really simple like

> rails g migration AddImageToBusiness

or

> rails g model Article

Even if I make a mistake like:

> rails g migr

It gives me no error, nothing, the terminal just waits the next command like nothing happened.

I can upload screenshots if necessary.

Anyone encountered anything like this or have any idea how to troubleshoot that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add some details like the command you're using, the rails version, anything that could helps us to reproduce your error?

Comment: @codingaddicted I am really sorry, I edited the question. Please let me know if I can do anything else.

Comment: I have this strange behavior once on a test server. Based on nothing I just reinstall everything. If your using rvm can you try switching to new or different ruby version, try a new gemset and bundle again?

Comment: try gem update --system

Comment: @codingaddicted I tried what you suggested but without results.

Comment: @Boltz0r sweet jesus that worked! What does "-system" mean here?
I also tried gem update alone and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gem update --system
```

It updates gem, rails and all it's dependencies, so you probably had something wrongly installed or some version was wrong

Comment: Simply "gem update" didn't work. Hope someone saves a lot of his time upon finding this post!